# Dynamic table display using kivy and sqlite 3

Tags: python, listview, sqlite, kivy

I am working on a GUI to manage inventory *(Python 3.4, Sqlite3 and Kivy 1.9.1)* and the idea is to be able to recognize products based on their different features, which are listed in a database.

Is there a way to display a sqlite table using kivy ? I think a `ListView` could be the solution but I am really struggling to understand how to make a `CustomListItem` with the right `args_converter` to get several columns with different labels in them.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can use `RecycleView` for this.
Try this example:

```
import sqlite3 as lite

con = lite.connect('test.db')
cur = con.cursor()

try:
    with con:
        cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Cars(Id INT, Name TEXT, Price INT)")
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(1,'Audi',52642)")
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(2,'Mercedes',57127)")
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(3,'Skoda',9000)")
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(4,'Volvo',29000)")
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(5,'Bentley',350000)")
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(6,'Citroen',21000)")
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(7,'Hummer',41400)")
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(8,'Volkswagen',21600)")
except:
    pass


from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ListProperty


Builder.load_string("""

<MyLayout>:
    Button:
        text: "Get data"
        on_press: root.get_data()
    RecycleView:
        data: [{'text':"Id:{} Brand:{} Km:{}".format(id,name,km)} for id,name,km in root.rows]
        viewclass: "Label"
        RecycleBoxLayout:
            default_size: None, dp(56)
            default_size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            orientation: 'vertical'

""")


class MyLayout(BoxLayout):
    rows = ListProperty([("Id","Brand","Price")])
    def get_data(self):
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Cars")
        self.rows = cur.fetchall()
        print(self.rows)


runTouchApp(MyLayout())
```

Comment: It seems to be a great solution but the RecycleView Widget is not included in the 1.9.1 version, or did I missed a part in the installation process on Windows ?

Comment: Hey, I was just looking at this solution for a thing I'm doing. I notice that you action the "get data" function when a button is pressed. Is there anyway to get it to automatically load into your tables and not have to press a button?

Comment: @Kaish Yea, you can get in `__init__` or in kv `on_kv_post` or in the `get_data()` method, do `return cur.fetchall()` and then in kv, `rows: get_data()` . These are only a few of many ways.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly modifying the original solution from @el3ien for better look and feel :-

```
import sqlite3 as lite

con = lite.connect('test.db')
cur = con.cursor()

try:
    with con:
        cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Cars(Id INT, Name TEXT, Price INT)")
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(1,'Audi',52642)")
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(2,'Mercedes',57127)")
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(3,'Skoda',9000)")
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(4,'Volvo',29000)")
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(5,'Bentley',350000)")
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(6,'Citroen',21000)")
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(7,'Hummer',41400)")
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(8,'Volkswagen',21600)")
except:
    pass


from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ListProperty


Builder.load_string("""

<MyLayout>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: 0.1
        Label:
            text: 'ID'
        Label:
            text: 'Brand'
        Label:
            text: 'Km'
    BoxLayout:
        RecycleView:
            data: [{'text':"{}".format(id)} for id,name,km in root.rows]
            viewclass: "Label"
            RecycleBoxLayout:
                default_size: None, dp(56)
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                orientation: "vertical"
        RecycleView:
            data: [{'text':"{}".format(name)} for id,name,km in root.rows]
            viewclass: "Label"
            RecycleBoxLayout:
                default_size: None, dp(56)
                orientation: "vertical"
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
        RecycleView:
            data: [{'text':"{}".format(km)} for id,name,km in root.rows]
            viewclass: "Label"
            RecycleBoxLayout:
                default_size: None, dp(56)
                orientation: "vertical"
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
    Button:
        size_hint_y: 0.1
        text: "Get data"
        on_press: root.get_data()

""")


class MyLayout(BoxLayout):
    rows = ListProperty([("Id","Brand","Km Run")])
    def get_data(self):
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Cars")
        self.rows = cur.fetchall()
        print(self.rows)


runTouchApp(MyLayout())
```

Comment: Output: https://i.imgur.com/2LuLarL.png