# Kivy: Listview implementation for a kivy page using MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, kivy

I'm creating a page using Kivy UI, and I need a table inserted with values from a MySQL table which I can interact with them and basically switch to a new page with the info of the mysql table row. My problem is creating the table. I can't seem to find tutorials using mysql, or even a lot of information about ListView and RecyclerView. I tried assigning everything into a list, but I had trouble with that, Kivy works funny with lists and it makes me very confused.

My questions,

1. How would I want to implement a Table in the given class (Below)?
2. What would be considered a better way to do it, with ListView, or with RecyclerView?

---

```
class EmployeePage(Screen):
    attempt = Employee.ObjEmployee()
    #The mysql connection and values which are used to take the whole row
    connection: Connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                                         port=3306,
                                         user='root',
                                         password='root',
                                         db='hrdb')


    cursorObject = connection.cursor()
    cursorObject.execute('SELECT `firstName`,`lastName`, `employeeID` 
    from `employeeprofile`')

    numRows = int(cursorObject.rowcount) #number of rows

    #The area which im stuck on right now. 
    data = [{'text': '''Value''', 'is_selected': False} for x in 
    range(0,numRows)]
    args_converter = lambda row_index, rec: {'text': rec['text'],
                                         'size_hint_y': None,
                                         'height': 25}

    list_adapter = ListAdapter(data=data,
                           args_converter=args_converter,
                           cls=ListItemButton,
                           selection_mode='single',
                           allow_empty_selection=False)

    list_view = ListView(adapter=list_adapter)
```

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43711589/dynamic-table-display-using-kivy-and-sqlite-3/43712089#43712089

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful. Got it running